# Get form input values into Javascript without PHP

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to find a way that I can import all of the values from a form into a Javascript without using PHP because I am unable to use PHP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example in your html:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="myUniqueId" value="value" />
```

and in your javascript:

```
var nameValue = document.getElementById("myUniqueId").value;
```

Hope it will help you :)

EDIT: An example to get all values... But if you can provide a small part of code to let me see how you are submitting your form will help me to give a better solution.

```
<button onclick="getAllFormValues()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: How could I make it so that it only gets the value once the form has been submitted?

Comment: Can you put this part of your code to let me write an easy way to do it? If you haven't write it yet, an easy and quick way to do that is to make a button with a function called with the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of an input you can use something like this:

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById('input_id').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have all form data together in serialized form like this.

```
var formdata= $('#form_id').serialize();
```

also you can store one element at a time like this.

in javascript

```
var name =document.getElementById('name_id').value;
var userName =document.getElementById('nameName').value;
```

in jquery

```
var name =$('#name_id').val();
var userName =$('#userName').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

i have created a jsfiddle example for you to check

```js
$(function(){
    $("#submit").on('click',function(){
        var myvalue ='';
        var $myform = $('#myform :input');    
        console.log($myform);
        $myform.each(function(){
           myvalue += $(this).val()+"<br>";       
        });
        console.log(myvalue);
      $('#values').html(myvalue);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="" method="">
    <input type="text" name="im1" value="my value" />
    <input type="text" name="im2" value="my value 1" />
    <input type="text" name="im2" value="my value 2" />
    <select name="imselect">
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1 </option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2 </option>
        <option value="Option 3">Option 3 </option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Get Value" />
        
</form>
<div id="values"></div>
```